# Generate and add L.control.layers from GeoJson properties to Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, markers, ajax

I have a problem with L.control.layer on [this code](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/dup/1/edit?html,output), the control is added but he put another marker on top of the correct one.

Naturally, I'd like to generate the layers from the results, not adding new ones.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating new markers right here:

```
 overlays[destination] = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
```

Just don't. Refer to the existing instances instead.

Comment: I think I don't get it, I changed this with `overlays[destination] = geoJsonLayer;` and it's still not what's expected.

Comment: Iterate through the individual markers inside your instance of `geoJsonLayer`.

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to let me find the answer but I still missing the thing, [Here is where I'm blocked now](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/wuk/edit?html,output).

Comment: You're on the right track, but you're still overcomplicating things. Be more aware of the contents of your variables (is that a string? or is that a geojson structure? or is that an instance of `L.Marker`?). See https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/safa/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Got it, "overcomplicating things" is what I do the best way ;) Thank you for your support.

Comment: Finally, it doesn't work as expected. In my [example](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/tona/2/edit?html,output), the legend doesn't take all the common destinations.