# How to control dynamic layers?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, markers

In [a previous stackexchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215427/generate-and-add-l-control-layers-from-geojson-properties-to-leaflet)

I got help to use a geojson property to create layers on a map.

However, the layer control only keeps the latest point he gets so I can't switch on/off all points of a "destination".

If all markers have a different destination it will work but if some markers shares same destination it fails.

Here is the [playground](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/tona/edit?html,output).

The geojson used is just an extract for the test. I 'need' to place hundreds of points in a few categories ("destination" in my case). Let's say, all museum and all schools, and I'd like to control the visibility of the layer on the map.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478202/leaflet-how-to-toggle-geojson-feature-properties-from-a-single-collection/33478639#33478639

Comment: @ghybs It's almost working, I notice that all the checkboxes are unchecked by default. So that once I click the control to uncollapse it, all the layers disappear. And I have to check them one by one to display them again.
[playground](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/tona/edit?html,output) is updated

Comment: That is probably because you add your GeoJSON layer to the map, instead of the Layer Groups that are actually referenced as overlays in your Layers Control.

Comment: Indeed but what if I want the layers to be shown by default ?
[playground](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/kuwi/edit?html,output) updated

Comment: Simply do the reverse as that one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207738/how-to-turn-off-geojson-layers-in-leaflet-when-the-site-starts/207760#207760 (i.e. add your Layer Groups to map)

Comment: @ghybs I'm confuse because if I do that I'm back with the previous situation, all points are shown but all the checkboxes are unchecked. I just can't find how to add my GeoJSON layer to overlays instead of map (?). I tried with `.addTo(overlays)` without luck...

Comment: Add your **Layer Groups** to map, not your GeoJSON group. The ones that are referenced as overlays in your Layers Control.

Comment: That's it ! I'm publishing the answer for others, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the solution](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/dati/edit?html,output), comments from @ghybs where valuable